# How to prevent remote file injection using Django and Python

Tags: python, django

I need to prevent from remote file attack using Python. I am providing my code below.

```
if request.GET.get('file') is not None and request.GET.get('file') != '':
    file = request.GET.get('file')
    response = urllib.urlopen(file)
    lines = response.readlines()
    return HttpResponse(content=lines, content_type="text/html")
else:
    return render(request, 'plant/home.html', {'count': 1})
```

Here if someone calling the query string value like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/createfile/?file=https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=N46zWczCGojT8geN-pvwCg` then remotes are also including here I need to prevent this remote file inclusion.

Comment: Get the `url` and check if it contains `url` of remote file ??

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar : Can you share your idea in a post.

Comment: What would an acceptable file url be? You should create a white list function and test the url against that. An illegal file url should result in a 400 response.

Comment: The acceptable file are only `csv` files and that should be read only. Can you   share your idea in a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_full_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path) to get the url in your view and check if it contains some external url in file path.

```
full_path = request.get_full_path()

if request.GET.get('file') is not None and request.GET.get('file') != '' and full_path.find('http') == -1:
    file = request.GET.get('file')
    response = urllib.urlopen(file)
    lines = response.readlines()
    return HttpResponse(content=lines, content_type="text/html")
else:
    return render(request, 'plant/home.html', {'count': 1})
```

Comment: Where that `full_path` is validating to prevent this.

Comment: @satya I've updated my answer. please check if this works.

Comment: @satya If it's working and you don't find any better way, please consider upvoting or accepting the answer.